# Deployment: pageerror at /personal-site/: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: node.js, npm

I am try to use this repos: https://github.com/mldangelo/personal-site. but when i try to built the GH page. I am getting this bug

```
 pageerror at /personal-site/: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

✅ crawled 1 out of 1 (/personal-site/)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! personal-site@2.1.0 postbuild: react-snap
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the personal-site@2.1.0 postbuild script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! /Users/kamel/.npm/_logs/2020-09-26T01_36_25_030Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! personal-site@2.1.0 predeploy: npm run build && cp -r public/* build/
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the personal-site@2.1.0 predeploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! /Users/kamel/.npm/_logs/2020-09-26T01_36_25_067Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Re-download the entire repo and build fresh.  If it builds, then your modifications were the fault.  We'll need to see those to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`ELIFECYCLE` errors usually mean something was mismatched.

Refresh `npm` and delete `node_modules`

```
$ npm cache clean --force
$ rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
$ npm install
```

Comment: I did it, and got this: added 1430 packages from 646 contributors and audited 1432 packages in 143.121s
found 2 low severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

is this effect buliding?

Comment: as the end user, `npm audit` issues are probably not yours.  Does it work now?`

Comment: i got :1-  Low           │ Prototype Pollution
2- Low           │ Denial of Service